# Using KnowledgeAgent with changeset.xml provided by Gunvor

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor

I was new to Drools and trying to try out its integration with Gunvor because we want to have our application capable to dynamically use latest rules created by user.

I am using Drools and Guvnor 5.5.

I start by creating a package in Gunvor, and I created a testing client with code like this:

```
ResourceFactory.getResourceChangeScannerService().start();
ResourceFactory.getResourceChangeNotifierService().start();
KnowledgeAgent agent =
        KnowledgeAgentFactory.newKnowledgeAgent("validation agent");
agent.applyChangeSet(changeSetUrlResource);
StatefulKnowledgeSession session =
        agent.getKnowledgeBase().newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
// play with session
```

The problem I am facing is the way to provide the changeset.xml

First I created the changeset.xml and put that in my classpath, and prepare changeSetUrlResource by something like `changeSetUrlResource = ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("drools/ChangeSet.xml")` with content like

```
<change-set xmlns='http://drools.org/drools-5.0/change-set'
    xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
    xs:schemaLocation='http://drools.org/drools-5.0/change-set http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/labs/labs/jbossrules/trunk/drools-api/src/main/resources/change-set-1.0.0.xsd' >
    <add>
         <resource source='http://localhost:8080/guvnor/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/package/test/LATEST' type='PKG'
         basicAuthentication="enabled" username="guest" password="guest"/>
    </add>
</change-set>
```

Such approach works.

Then I see the changeset.xml is provided directly from Gunvor and I want to make use of it.  I tried to do something like this:

```
UrlResource changeSetUrlResource = (UrlResource)ResourceFactory.newUrlResource(
    "http://localhost:8080/guvnor/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/package/test/LATEST/ChangeSet.xml");
changeSetUrlResource.setBasicAuthentication("enabled");
changeSetUrlResource.setUsername("guest");
changeSetUrlResource.setPassword("guest");
```

This approach is not working.  It complains for 401 when accessing `http://localhost:8080/guvnor/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/package/test/LATEST`.  The ChangeSet.xml provided by Gunvor is not containing authentication information.

Given that Gunvor is providing the ChangeSet.xml, I believe there is a proper way to use that with the knowledge agent.  However did quite some search on the web and I cannot find related information except totally turning off authentication in Gunvor.

What should be the right way to configure Drools KnowledgeAgent to make use of the changeset.xml on Gunvor?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using the changest over guvnor URL is the right approach. Use URL authentication:

```
        UrlResource url = (UrlResource) ResourceFactory.newUrlResource(changeSetUrl);
        url.setBasicAuthentication("enabled");
        url.setUsername(userName);
        url.setPassword(pass);
```

Comment: That's what I have mentioned in my question.  It doesn't work.  Connecting to changeset URL works, but the agent will connect to the URL quoted in the changeset xml, that part is failing.  The authentication information used for connecting to changeset URL is not carried over to that subsequent connection :(  Anything I have missed?

Comment: Username and Password? Are you able to login to guvnor from browser with these credentials?

Comment: I can.  As I mentioned in my original question, I have tried exactly the same way you mentioned, and it is complaining for 401 for accessing the package URL (as quoted in Gunvor's changeset.xml)

Comment: [This](http://pastebin.com/1fje3V0D) is my working code to create Knowledge Base. Please see if it is helpful.

Comment: I believe it will work but your code doesn't use KnowledgeAgent.  FYI in case you overlooked: KnowledgeAgent is for monitoring the resource used to create KnowledgeBase, and when there is update in resource, it will update/re-create the knowledgeBase.  However in your code you are simply creating the KnowledgeBase directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think authentication you are providing is for getting the changeSet from the guvnor over the web, but in ChangeSet file you are providing authentication information for particular resource like package or sth. I think try to take ChangeSet without authentication or use "guest" "guest" as username and password. One more thing you can go to your guvnor and there on the administrative left panel , you can give authentication or  permission (user permission) for a particular user for particular package.